# Batching not working in Kafka Producer with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am writing a Producer in Scala and I want to do batching. The way batching should work is, it should hold the messages in queue till it is full and then post all of them together on the topic. But somehow it's not working. The moment I start sending message, it starts posting the message one by one. Does anyone know how to use batching in Kafka Producer.

```
val kafkaStringSerializer = "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"
      val batchSize: java.lang.Integer = 163840
      val props = new Properties()
      props.put("key.serializer", kafkaStringSerializer)
      props.put("value.serializer", kafkaStringSerializer)
      props.put("batch.size", batchSize);
      props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")

      val producer = new KafkaProducer[String,String](props)

      val TOPIC="topic"
      val inlineMessage = "adsdasdddddssssssssssss"

      for(i<- 1 to 10){
        val record: ProducerRecord[String, String] = new ProducerRecord(TOPIC, inlineMessage )
        val futureResponse: Future[RecordMetadata] =  producer.send(record)
        futureResponse.isDone
        println("Future Response ==========>" + futureResponse.get().serializedValueSize())
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `linger.ms` in your props

By default, it is to zero, meaning that message is send immediatly if possible.
You can increase it (for example 100) so that batch occur - this means higher latency, but higher throughput.

`batch.size` is a maximum : if you reach it before `linger.ms` has passed, data will be sent without waiting more time.

To view the batches actually sent, you will need to configure your logging (batching s done on a background thread and you will not be able to view what batches are done with producer api - you can't send or receive batches, only send a record and receive its response, communication with broker via batch is done internally)

First, if not already done, bind a log4j properties file (`Dlog4j.configuration=file:path/to/log4j.properties`)

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stderr
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender=TRACE, stderr

log4j.appender.stderr=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stderr.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stderr.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
log4j.appender.stderr.Target=System.err
```

For example, I will receive

```
TRACE Sent produce request to 2: (type=ProduceRequest, magic=1, acks=1, timeout=30000, partitionRecords=({test-1=[(record=LegacyRecordBatch(offset=0, Record(magic=1, attributes=0, compression=NONE, crc=2237306008, CreateTime=1502444105996, key=0 bytes, value=2 bytes))), (record=LegacyRecordBatch(offset=1, Record(magic=1, attributes=0, compression=NONE, crc=3259548815, CreateTime=1502444106029, key=0 bytes, value=2 bytes)))]}), transactionalId='' (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
```

Which is a batch of 2 data. Batch will contain records send to a same broker

Then, play with batch.size and linger.ms to see the difference. Note that a record contain some overhead, so a batch.size of 1000 will not contain 10 messages of size 100

Note that I did not find documentation which stated all logger and what they do (like log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender). You can enable DEBUG/TRACE on rootLogger and find the data you want, or [explore the code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/Sender.java#L667)

Comment: I did. I have  props.put("linger.ms", 5000). But still not working. Now I see my messages coming with a delay of 5 sec. The message is still coming one by one but with a delay of 5 sec.

Comment: The messages are stored in batches and fetched in batches but they are still presented to the consumer as individual messages. Don't expect to read a single message and get a batch of messages as a response. That's not how Kafka batching works.

Comment: So, if I have to verify my batching is done correctly. How can I verify it?

Comment: You could look at the JMX metrics on the broker which counts the number of produce requests and the number of fetch requests. If there is batching then the number of requests will be lower than the number of messages. Another way would be to use wireshark or another network packet analyzer to see the Kafka requests and content on the wire.

Answer (score 0):

Your are producing the data to the Kafka server synchronously. Means, the moment you call `producer.send` with `futureResponse.get`, it will return only after the data gets stored in the Kafka Server.

Store the response in a separate list, and call `futureResponse.get` outside the `for` loop.

With default [configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs), Kafka supports batching, see `linger.ms` and `batch.size`

```
List<Future<RecordMetadata>> responses = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC, inlineMessage);
    Future<RecordMetadata> response = producer.send(record);
    responses.add(response);
}

for (Future<RecordMetadata> response : responses) {
    response.get(); // verify whether the message is sent to the broker.
}
```